# Debian Repo being used on Ubuntu and cannot be removed

Tags: apt, software-sources, debian

My Issue:

```
GPG error: http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 W: The repository 'http://http.debian.net/debian stretch-backports InRelease' is not signed.
```

I am at a loss here. Not sure how I managed this but for some reason my Ubuntu box is trying to use a debian source and is failing. The problem is this is not listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list` so I cannot remove it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as my google searches have yielded no results?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Check the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` maybe you got it added there.

Comment: No need to, maybe you can look into how to format the question here a bit and maybe even write your own answer to your question :)

Comment: @Videonauth likely gave the answer. On the command line you can automate that search with "grep -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d debian.org".